# What am I doing wrong with my rigged body?

Tags: rigging, armature

I just started "playing" with blender after realising that I have to be able to design my own objects to make my own game without keep on using someone else's work/Unity Asset store prefabs. I never designed anything so, yeah, I can say I'm pretty horrible at it.

Everything was going somewhat fine but I don't know why my character's body is not moving smoothly at all. Could you tell me if I'm doing something wrong please?

Here's a [video showing the current issue](https://streamable.com/o08g8) (I know I can use the paint brush to correct the distorted shapes when I rotate the figure but I'm pretty sure I screwed up somewhere with the armature movement part as it lacks smoothness)

**EDIT: Here's a download link if you want to see my file:** [image]

Comment: please share your file so that we can see

Comment: To share your file please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I just posted a download link from wetransfer (main post), is it ok like that or do I have to go through that way @Dontwalk ?

Also thanks for the answers, but either I'm blind or I don't really know which kind of dependency I'm missing...

Comment: @ 4ever an Amateur - It is best to use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so it will always be associated with your question for people searching for answers in the future.

Comment: Done, @Dontwalk . Thank you for letting me know. Post updated.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate the *Snap* option (magnet icon on the horizontal bottom bar of your 3D view).

Comment: Don't tell me it was this easy...I'll check it out once I get back home. Thanks for the comment, @moonboots